# Intuitive Explanation of Continuity, Inverse Image Definition

Tags: analysis, continuity

I understand the intuition behind the epsilon-delta definition of continuity when working in $\mathbb{R}$: Given a point $a$, all points within a little distance of $a$ are also within a little distance (and $0$ counts as "little" :)) from $f(a)$. But I'm having difficulty understanding the intuition behind the equivalent definition: a function f is continuous if $f^{-1}$ pulls open sets to open sets—i.e., V open in the image of f implies $f^{-1}$(V) open.

(Note: It turns out that my definition is wrong: I need to say "$V$ open in the co-domain implies $f^{-1}(V)$ open." See below.)

Consider the function $f(x)$ = {x when x $\le$ 0, x + 1 when x $\gt$ 0}. Using the epsilon-delta approach, the function is discontinuous at 0 because the point $\frac 14$ is close to 0, but the point f($\frac 14$) = $\frac 54$ is miles away from $f(0) = 0$.

Here's what I can't figure out: what is the open set $V$ in the image of f such that $f^{-1}$($V$) is not open?

(Note: It turns out that this particular question is answered well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287574/proving-continuity-using-the-topological-definition) by [Ben West](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/37097/ben-west). The open set $V$ needs to be in the [co-domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) of $f$, not the image of $f$. In this case, the codomain of f is $\mathbb R$, so the restriction I created below was needless.

In addition, it looks like I could have just I just chosen my open set in the codomain of $f$ to be $V_2 = \mathbb R$ and note that $f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is no longer an open set.

Edit: I see now that this reasoning is wrong, as $f^{-1}(V_2)$ is just $\mathbb R$.

My prior (false) reasoning is below, in case anyone finds it useful. I've also followed it with one more question.)

Here's what I tried and rejected. $V_1$ = {y = f(x), -1/2 $\lt$ y $\lt$ 1/2}. I rejected this choice for the open set we want because it doesn't seem to me that {0 $\lt$ y $\lt$ 1/2} is in the image of f. The part of $V_1$ that is in the image of f is the half open interval {-1/2 $\lt$ y $\le$ 0}. If this set $V_1$ did qualify, we could use a similar argument to "prove" that {$g(x) = -x\ when\ x \le 0, \mathrm{undefined\
otherwise}$} was discontinuous at $0$.

Question: Take the function g above. Do we just say that $\mathbb R^+$ is not in its codomain?

Comment: If $f:X\to\mathbb R$ then $f^{-1}(\mathbb R)=X$ which is certainly open.

Comment: For your function $f$ which is discontinuous at $0$, take $V$ to be an interval around $0$, i.e. $(-\delta, \delta)$ where $\delta\lt 1$. What is $f^{-1}((-\delta, \delta))$?

Comment: $g$ is continuous on its domain $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: Right, I see now that f inverse of R is all of R. That was silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1). If $f(x)=x$ when $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x+1 $ when $x>0$ then $f^{-1}(-\infty,1/2)=(-\infty,0]$ is not open.

(2). For any $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$  let $f''\Bbb R=\{f(x): x\in \Bbb R\}.$ This is a notation used in Set Theory.  Then for any $S\subset \Bbb R$ we have $f^{-1}S=f^{-1}(S\cap f''\Bbb  R)$.

(3).  For any $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$: If $S$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$ then $S\cap f''\Bbb R$ is an open subset of the space $f''\Bbb R.$ And if $f^{-1}S$ is not open in $\Bbb R$ then neither is $f^{-1}(S\cap f''\Bbb R)$ because it's the same set.

(4). So for the $f$ in the question let  $S=(-\infty,1/2)$  and $T=S\cap f''\Bbb R=(-\infty,0]$. We have $S\cap f''\Bbb R=T,$ which is open in $f''\Bbb R.$

And $f^{-1}T=$ $f^{-1}(S\cap f''\Bbb R)=$ $f^{-1}S=$ $(-\infty,0],$ which is not open in the domain, $\Bbb R.$

Note: In general, any $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff ... (i)... $f:X\to Y'$ is continuous for all $Y'$ such that $f''X\subset Y'\subset Y,$...(ii)... iff $f:X\to Y'$ is continuous for at least one $Y'$ such that $f''X\subset Y'\subset Y, $...(iii)...iff   $f:X\to f''X$ is continuous.

Footnote: When $A\subset$ dom($f)$ then $f''A$  (read $f$-double-prime-$A$) is $\{f(a):a\in A\}. $ Set theorists prefer this to $f(A)$ for the image of $A$ because  a subset $A$ of dom($f$) could also be a member of the domain of $f$, which would make $f(A)$ ambiguous.

Comment: You said "For any f:ℝ→ℝ: If S is an open subset of ℝ then S∩f″ℝ is an open subset of the space f″ℝ." This is useful. I had not known that an interval $$[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$$ was considered open as a subspace under the relative topology.

Comment: You said "For any f:ℝ→ℝ: If S is an open subset of ℝ then S∩f″ℝ is an open subset of the space f″ℝ." Can you say more about this? Is it related to the fact that $f'' \mathbb R$, under the relative topology, is by definition both open and closed, and thus open?

Comment: Let $T$ be the topology on $\Bbb R.$  The subspace topology on $f''\Bbb R$ is by definition $\{t\cap f''\Bbb R: t\in T\},$  which includes the set $S\cap f''\Bbb R$ when $S\in T.$

Answer (score 0):

The open set in the image could have been $$(-1/2,0] = (-1/2, 1/2 )\cup Im (f)$$  which is an open set in the the image of f(x) with the relative topology.

That is open sets in $(-\infty, 0] \cup \{1\}$  are intersection of open sets in $R$ with the set  $(-\infty, 0]\cup \{1\}$

Comment: Why wouldn't the open set in the image be $$(-1/2,0] = (-1/2,1/2) \cap Im(f)$$?

Comment: It is the same thing. The singleton \{1\}  does not  change our open set.